# DSpace, Error edit-item with more than 1000 bitstreams

Tags: java, tomcat, dspace

I am experiencing an error trying to edit the metadata fields of a file in DSpace with 1000 bitstreams.

I am using DSpace v5.1 with Apache Tomcat 8.0.26 in a machine with Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a repository with more than 3000 items with various numbers of bitstreams per item (1 to 200). I have successfully inserted a document with 1000 bitstreams, but when I am going to edit the metadata field via JSPUI, the server returns an internal error message. First, I thought it was due to the excessive number of parameters on the HTTP request, so I've modified the maximum number of parameters at Tomcat's HTTP connector config to less than zero (`maxParameterCount="-1"` at conf/server.xml), so it would have no limit of number of parameters. There is nothing wrong on Tomcat's log when the error happens, so I believe it's related to DSpace.

The log from the error at DSpace (`dspace.log.2016-11-25` file) is the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.dspace.handle.HandleManager.findHandle(HandleManager.java:404)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.admin.EditItemServlet.doDSPost(EditItemServlet.java:207)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:115)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doPost(DSpaceServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.filter.RegisteredOnlyFilter.doFilter(RegisteredOnlyFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I just have this problem. Thanks to your clue, I found the solution.

You have to increase "maxPostSize" too. The default of 2mb is not enough for DSpace when there are many bitstreams. I have about 300 bitstreams and it's already over 2mb POST when edit.